# C# Events and Lambdas, alternative to null check?

Tags: c#

Does anybody see any drawbacks? It should be noted that you can't remove anonymous methods from an event delegate list, I'm aware of that (actually that was the conceptual motivation for this).

The goal here is an alternative to:

```
if (onFoo != null) onFoo.Invoke(this, null);
```

And the code:

```
public delegate void FooDelegate(object sender, EventArgs e);

public class EventTest
{
    public EventTest()
    {
        onFoo += (p,q) => { };
    }

    public FireFoo()
    {
         onFoo.Invoke(this, null);
    }

    public event FooDelegate onFoo;
```

}

Comment: Well, you asked me not to ask, so I wont.

Comment: No major drawbacks come to mind. No advantages come to mind, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public event FooDelegate onFoo = delegate {};
```

Comment: i'm not sure what you're trying to say. Perhaps "delegate (p, q) {};"? The delegate takes two parameters.

Comment: with this event initialization you can fire event without check for null. No, just delegate {}.

Comment: ill vote this answer if it works, testing it tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 5):

One alternative is to make an extension method instead:

```
public static class EventExtensions {
    public static void Fire<T>(this EventHandler<EventArgs<T>> handler, object sender, T args) {
        if (handler != null)
            handler(sender, new EventArgs<T>(args));
    }
}
```

Now it's just:

```
TimeExpired.Fire(this, new EventArgs());
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions of Visual Studio *automatically* suggest to use a [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators):

```
onFoo?.Invoke(this, null);
```

<sub>(whenever this kind of code is encountered: `if (onFoo != null) onFoo.Invoke(this, null)`).</sub>

This operator became available with the release of C# 6.0 in 2015.